# Django iterate on values()

Tags: python, django

I have somethink like this:

```
vmware = Vmware.objects.values('pk', 'hostname')
```

the result :

```
<QuerySet [{'pk': 1, 'hostname': 'ste1vvcsa'}, {'pk': 3, 'hostname': 'ste1vvcsatest'}]>
```

I want to iterate on it and retreive the values of pk and hostname

I have an error when I do somethink like this:

```
for i in vwmare:
  print(i.hostname)
```

Error : `AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'hostname'`

Comment: Values creates a QuerySet of dictionaries so you’ll want to do something like `i["hostname"]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can not use the dot (.) operator on dictionary keys. try this:

```
for i in vwmare:
    print(i["hostname"])
```

Comment: thank you. I still have a lot to learn.

Comment: Your welcome. me to :)

Answer (score 1):

It's a dictionary, hence you access the value of a key by *subscripting*:

```
for i in vwmare:
    print(i['hostname'])
```

Comment: yeah it's working. thanks.